# My ajax append data did not append the last data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append

I don't know why. The append is not working, every time I click, the ajax runs and shows the new data, it just won't append the last data.
It didn't show any error on the firebug console, what have I done wrong?

The weird thing is that the ajax won't run if I remove the `beforeSend`. If I remove the `beforeSend` and change the `append` to `html(data)`, it runs again. I really don't understand.

**JS:**

```
$tag_link_list = $('#tag_link_list');
current_page = '1';
click_term = '1';
var data = {
    action: 'click_symptom',
    postSearchNonce: MyAjaxSearch.postSearchNonce,
    click_term: click_term,
    p: current_page
};

$.ajax({
    url: MyAjaxSearch.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data) {
            $tag_link_list.append(data);
            current_page++
        } else {
            $('#messages_list').html('<center>No result to show.</center>');
        }
    }
}); //ajax
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tag_link_list" class="tag_link_list">
    <?php
        $tag_d_common = 'd_common';
        $stm          = $db->prepare("SELECT words_common FROM disease_d WHERE tag_d=:tag_d");
        $stm->bindParam(':tag_d', $tag_d_common);

        $stm->execute();
        $symptom_d = $stm->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //show the tags from database
        foreach ($symptom_d as $symptom) {
            $symptom = $symptom['words_common'];
            echo "<a class='tag_link'  href='$symptom' >$symptom</a>";
        }
    ?>
</div><!--tag_link_list-->
```

Comment: Check your error console in your web browser. Are there any errors?

Comment: does the request succeed? debug it and tell us what exactly happens. If the button refreshes the browser, add `event.preventDefault()` to the event.

Comment: the console didn't give me any error, ajax has not problem to run, it show the data. It just won't append the last data.

Comment: Can you post what the return value is? Throw console.log(data) in the top of your success callback and that value here.

Comment: Have you tried using `$('#tag_link_list').append(data);` instead of `$tag_link_list.append(data);` (and remove `$tag_link_list = $('#tag_link_list');`)? Since the `$` sign is reserved for jQuery, it might mess things up if you use that same sign as a prefix for your variable